# symfony одновременные запросы

Tags: php, telegram-bot, symfony4

Делаю бота для телеграмма, использую webhook. Испытал проблему, что одновременно не  возможно работать с двумя и более пользователями. Пока функция обрабатывающая запрос от сервера телеграмма не закончит свое выполнение, запрос с сообщением от другого пользователя не начнет обрабатываться. С симфони я почти не знаком, нагуглить эту тему не вышло. Есть возможность решить данную проблему? Спасибо.

Когда пользователь пишет боту, сервер телеграмм вызывает mysite.com/tg, передав UpdateMessage (для этого я использую ngrok, чтобы localhost стал доступен извне). Из него я просто вытаскиваю айдишник чата и посылаю сообщение пользователю

```
/**
 * @Route("/tg", name="tg")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function tg(Request $request)
{
    $update = json_decode($request->getContent());
    $tgBot = new TgBot('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
    $tgBot->setMessage($update);

    $mas = explode(" ", "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing");
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($mas); ++$i) {
        $tgBot->sendMessage(
            $tgBot->getMessage()->getChat()->getId(),
            $mas[$i]
        );
    }
    return new JsonResponse(
        Response::HTTP_OK
    );
}
```

sendMessage просто вызывает API метод используя guzzle

Comment: Вам бы основы изучить.

Comment: @zalex, огромное спасибо за "помощь"

Comment: Поверьте, это лучшая помощь при данном вопросе.  Я могу вам ещё посоветовать использовать очереди, но скорее всего вы подумаете про меня плохо.

Comment: @zalex, я писал на spring'e и там нет проблем загрузить 2+ страницы одновременно. А сейчас мне нужно использовать php, и я предполагал что тут что-то с конфигом, ибо для меня это странно, что невозможно обработать более одной страницы одновременно

Comment: Во-первых я прошу прощения, я сразу не правильно понял вопрос. Забираю назад про "основы".  Это мое мудачество прет наружу, ему бы уже и спать наверное пора, но оно сидит на кухне и мудачит. Конечно я бы еще немного потошнил  начиная от имени метода в контроллере и заканчивая логики в нем же, но это другая история. 

По сути же - я не очень понял. Вы пытаетесь с двух разных вкладок одного браузера одновременно дергать данный роут ?  А используете наверное встроенный веб сервер ?

Comment: @zalex, "Вы пытаетесь с двух разных вкладок одного браузера одновременно дергать данный роут ?" - Нет, этот роут вообще не я дергаю) У телеграм бот апи есть два варианта получения обновлений. 1) Вручную вызвать api метод getUpdates, либо подписаться на обновления ( webhook ), т.е. я сообщаю серверу по какому роуту я хочу получать от него обновления. И как только какой-либо пользователь телеграма отправит сообщение моему боту, Телеграм дернет данный роут, и передаст всю информацию. Надеюсь понятнее объяснил. Да, использую встроенный сервер server:run, в нем собака зарыта?)

Comment: вероятнее всего. Если вы , например, работаете через nginx  и  php-fpm то там на каждый запрос создается thread (worker), как угодно... Однако предполагаю что через server:run у вас сервер работает в один поток и запросы попросту становятся в очередь. 

Однако даже в режиме nginx-php-fpm я встречал подобные проблемы , но только с включенным xdebug.

Comment: ну и закончив данную тему "чтобы наверняка" я все же бы порекомендовал бы вам использовать очереди, в этом случае вы бы даже имея подобные проблемы, не имели бы их в общем то.

Comment: @zalex, спасибо, но не могли бы вы уточнить о каких очередях вы говорите? Для меня очередь - это структура данных.

Comment: ага, понял вас.  Речь идет о RabbitMQ, как один из вариатнов или есть еще более модные нынче темы. 
Т.е. к вам приходит запрос, который отсылает сообщение в сервер очередей. В свою очередь у вас есть сервисы которые слушают постоянно сервер очередей, забирают предназначающиеся им сообщения и выполняют нужные функции с данными, которые содержаться в сообщениях. 

В небольших приложениях в этом смысла нет, однако когда все разростается, это чень полезно.

Comment: ага, еще раз вчитался, очереди тут не причем по больше части.

Comment: @zalex, спасибо за помощь, настроил локальный серв xampp, теперь не в однопоточном режиме работает.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что **php bin/console server:run** работает в однопоточном режиме. Если вы хотите, чтобы запросы обрабатывались одновременно, необходимо ставить локальный сервер, например **XAMPP**.